# Grouping similar items into an array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to group similar items in an array into new arrays. So far no luck, can anyone help?

```
int[] items = { T1, T4, T6, T1, T4, T20, T6 };
```

I want this to be grouped as below;

```
int[] One = { T1, T1 };
int[] two = { T6, T6 };
int[] three = { T20 };
int[] four = { T4, T4 };
```

so far I tried below, but I get a null value on arrays (one, two etc)

```
int[] one = items.Where(com => com == 8).ToArray();
```

result I get is;

```
one {int[0]}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could get an IEnumerable of arrays or you could create each array name "one", "two" and get a list from the previous arrays.  Which one do you want?

Comment: It's not clear what is expected output. You want to group by *variable name*? Not by value of variables?

Comment: @CharlesNRice each array name (one, two) are constant so those I can create. I'm just clueless on the grouping part.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I have a set of "items" in the main array called "items", I want to group them into separate arrays as below shown (one, two, etc)

Comment: @Nicolas78 so far i have tried : int[] one = items.Where(com => com == 8).ToArray();

Comment: @megazoid I think your question would benefit if you added that to the main body, and also described what came out and why it was wrong

Comment: This should have worked int[] one = items.Where(com => com == 8).ToArray(); with the exception that T1, T4, etc are not ints.

Comment: @CharlesNRice I tried with int as well, still the array is empty

Comment: @CharlesNRice hay, yes it worked. Thanks for the clarification. there was a type in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Group the items based on their equality then create an array for each group that contains items of the group.

```
var groups = items.GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.ToArray());
```

This query qill give you an `IEnumerable<int[]>` which contains four array of ints in this case. You can use `ToArray` or `ToList` after `Select` if you want to  access your elements by index like `groups[0]`.

Comment: Do you need the select in this case? What would just items.GroupBy(x => x) return?

Comment: it returns IEnumerable<IGrouping<int,int>>, I think OP wants IEnumrable<int[]>